# Do I have access to velocity fields between frames in fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have never used Blender before, I'm here to see if it can actually be beneficial for my case, I need to make a fluid simulation, but beside the simulation I need the velocity fields between frames. Which is possible if I programmed the whole thing from scratch. Im not sure if Blender can give access to these information or it just focus on the simulation part ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can, but you could compile Blender yourself to add that, if you really need it... Not a great solution, though

Comment: Thanks, The best then is I go code my own fluid simulation